# How to check if a group was not added in the gerrit CL?

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I am working in a large team. We are using `Git` with `Gerrit`. To ensure code quality with extensive review system, we have a gerrit group which we want to add for each commit (`CL`) from each developers, especially for `main` branch which we need to keep stable. All the reviewers of this group are senior members and they review each `CL` exclusively. But, some developers merging their `CL` without adding the group (may be unintentionally) and we cannot know that the CL is merged already. To avoid manual checking, I want to detect if the group was not added (i.e. all group members are not present as reviewers) in the `CL`. How can I do so?

Is there any API from gerrit which I can use?

Comment: Why don't you restrict who can give Code-Review +2 and submit changes to the special gerrit group that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [gerrit query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html), you can get the reviewers of a change:

```
ssh -p 29418 ${username}@${gerrithost} gerrit query commit:${sha1} --all-reviewers
```

The reviewers are listed like:

```
allReviewers:
name: Tom
email: Tom@foo.com
username: tom
```

You can add `--format=json` to get the output in json.

I'd suggest you add the group to reviewers automatically in Gerrit's hook, like `patch-set-created`.